# Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm reading data from a `csv` file with 7 million rows. Sample data in that file-

```
"dfg.AAIXpWU4Q","1"
"cvbc.AAU3aXfQ","1"
"T-L5aL1uT_OfFbk","1"
"D9TOXrA_LsQa-awVk","2"
"JWg8_0lGDWcH_9aDc","2"
"ewrq.AAbCVh5wA","1"
"ewrq.AALAC-Qku3heg","1"
"ewrq.AADSmhJ7A","2"
"ewrq.AAEAoHUNA","1"
"ewrq.AALfV5u-7Yg","1"
```

And I read it like-

```
>>> rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/file/*")

>>> rdd.take(2)
['"7wAfdgdfgd","7"', '"1x3Qdfgdf","1"']
​
# reading the RDD into a dataframe
>>> my_df = rdd.map(lambda x: (x.split(","))).toDF()

# changing column names
>>> df1 = my_df.selectExpr("_1 as user_id", "_2 as hits")

>>> df1.show(3)
+-------+----+
|user_id|hits|
+-------+----+
|"aYk...| "7"|
|"yDQ...| "1"|
|"qUU...|"13"|
+-------+----+
only showing top 3 rows

>>> df2 = df1.sort(col('hits').desc())
>>> df2.show(10)
```

But this gives me the following error-

`Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 2 fields are required while 18 values are provided.`

I'm guessing it's the way I convert the RDD to DF. Maybe the `x.split(",")` is not taking into account the bad data - how do I get around this issue?

Comment: It's likely that you have a bad record somewhere in your file that contains the delimiter inside the line. Spark is lazy, so you won't encounter the error until that specific part of your data needs to be acted on. In this case, the `sort` has to read the full file and that's causing the error.

Comment: i know what and why the error exists, i'm asking how do I circumvent this error?

Comment: It seems like your data is quoted, but the way you are reading it ignores the quotes. Instead try: `df = spark.read.csv("/path/to/file/*", quote='"', sep=",")` and if that doesn't work, try adding: `mode="DROPMALFORMED"`. [Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv).

Comment: @kev maybe you can specify the number max in the split, like `x.split(",",1)`, this may allow the df to be created, but won't remove the "bad formatted data"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by @pault's comment, I just did the following to solve this-

```
>>> rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/file/*")

# checking out how the data looks
>>> rdd.take(2)
['"7wAfdgdfgd","7"', '"1x3Qdfgdf","1"']

>>> my_df = spark.read.csv("/path/to/file/*", quote='"', sep=",")

>>> df1 = my_df.selectExpr("_c0 as user_id", "_c1 as hits")

>>> df1 = df1.withColumn("hits", df1["hits"].cast(IntegerType()))

>>> df2 = df1.sort(col('hits').desc())
```